# Windows Form Application "How do I increase the size of the button when the mouse hovers over the button?"

Tags: c#

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MouseMove == button1;)
        {
            button1.Size= 100;70;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I couldn't find how to write code

Comment: `if (MouseMove == button1)` is not how you install an event-handler.  You can use the designer to add a handler to the MouseEnter event on the button, it will produce code looking something like `button1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(button1_MouseEnter);` and then you can put your size-changing code inside a function named `button1_MouseEnter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
        private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Width = 100;
        button1.Height = 70;
    }
```

if you want to set size to the previous size after leaving the mouse, you can use this (for example it was 60 and 30 at first place):

```
    private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Width = 60;
        button1.Height = 30;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MouseEnter` event to capture the mouse cursor hovering over the button borders,
and the `MouseLeave` event to detect when the cursor leaves the button borders, in order to return it to its original size.

Here is one way to implement such functionality:

```
private Size OriginalButtonSize;
private Size HoveredSize;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OriginalButtonSize = this.button1.Size;
    HoveredSize = new Size(OriginalButtonSize.Width + 30, OriginalButtonSize.Height + 30);
}

private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Size = HoveredSize;
}

private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Size = OriginalButtonSize;
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Can you offset the top and left by half the increase too?